# Run dependency gem generator from my gem's generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am building my first gem for rails and it has a dependency on another gem (active_admin). I have added the active_admin as a dependency and it installs correctly when I run bundle install however I need to run the generator for active_admin as its a required step of the installation.

How can I get my generator to run the active_admin generator?

Here is my generator:

```
require 'rails/generators'
module Poly
    module Generators
        class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
            source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

            def install_active_admin
                # run the generator for active admin here:
                # e.g.
                # rails generate active_admin:install
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Am I going about this the right way? and how can I do what I'm trying to do.

If you need any other info to help answer this question please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: according to the rails guides on generators (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#generate), you can just call `generate "active_admin:install"`

Comment: @LesNightingill Thank you. I stumbled upon this shortly after posting this, hadn't got round to posting an answer. If you post this comment as an answer I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ref: [Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#generate)

The `generate` method can be called from *within* a generator, to call other generators.

So you just need `generate "active_admin:install"`